# Have I found a memory leak in erb or am I missing something essential? Please advise

Tags: html, ruby, memory, erb

Please help me understand why the memory of this seemingly simple erb rendering loop grows in size forever.

"alltext.erb" is a basic text file that looks something like this:

```
<% 5000000.times do %>
  spam
<% end %>
```

The test case below grows in memory until it eventually caps at ~670MB

```
require 'erb'

filename = File.expand_path("../alltext.erb", __FILE__)
file_contents = File.read(filename)
renderer = ERB.new(file_contents)

# Undiagnosed memory leak below...
loop do

  html = renderer.result();

  # Display memory in kb
  puts `ps -o rss= -p #{Process.pid}`.to_i

  # Attempt to clear variables and force garbage collection
  html = nil
  filename = nil
  file_contents = nil
  renderer = nil
  GC.start

  # Display memory in kb
  puts `ps -o rss= -p #{Process.pid}`.to_i

  sleep(5)
end
```

I would expect that setting all variables to nil and forcing garbage collection, as well as going out of scope (proceeding to the next iteration of the forever loop) would free up some memory.  Please help me understand what I am missing here.

My ruby version is 1.9.2-p180.
I am on OSX but this is test case is replicating behavior observed on a current Ubuntu server.

Comment: You are creating files and never close them. This works for smalls scripts but if you create like infinity of them it does not work.

Comment: I updated the code to reflect this suggestion but it does not affect the memory  leak.  Thank you though.

Comment: I couldn't get this to run more than one iteration without removing `renderer = nil`.  When I do that, it runs, but does not leak in MRI 1.9.3-p125.

Comment: Wait... you do not have access to your renderer after the first iteration... as it becomes nil.

Comment: We have the exact same issue: a very simple loop in the erb file makes the memory grow indefinitely: Ruby 1.8.7-p370, Rails 2.3.11 (I know - it's old, don't blame me).

Answer (score 2):

As ayckoster suggested, "You are creating files and never close them". Use:

```
file_contents = File.read(filename)
```

instead of:

```
file_contents = File.new(filename).read
```

Comment: Thank you for the input.  I tried this adjustment to no avail.  I have also tried leaving the file declarations out of the loop (this also is ineffective).  To clarify, the process seems to grow in memory for a period and then to cap out.  For example, with the spam repeated 5,000,000 times, this test loop caps at about 670MB.  I wonder how this can happen even though no objects/references should be kept between loops.